# Sonarlint not syncing with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

Using Sonarlint 3.2 in Eclipse with SonarQube 5.6.6.

I have successfully bound my project(s) in Eclipse to SonarQube. However, Sonarlint is reporting no issues, while issues are reported in SonarQube. I have been unsuccesfull in resolving the error.

Below is the log file (a little bit edited for readability...) of Sonarlint console. What surprises me are the "No language available" and "No analyzers installed" messages.

Sonarlint stand alone gives expected results. The connected mode to SonarQube gives 0 issues.

```
Trigger: EDITOR_OPEN
SonarLint analysis of file xxx.java...
Connected mode (using configuration of 'xxx' in server 'xxx')
Starting analysis with configuration:
[
  moduleKey: xxx
  baseDir: xxx
  workDir: C:\Werkomgeving\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\LWBBusinessRules\org.sonarlint.eclipse.core
  extraProperties: {sonar.java.source=1.6, sonar.java.target=1.6, sonar.libraries=yyyyy, sonar.binaries=C:xxx, sonar.java.binaries=C:xxx, sonar.java.test.binaries=C:xxx}
  inputFiles: [
    xxx.java
  ]
]

No language available
No analyzers installed
Start analysis
Quality profiles:
Index files
Setting filesystem encoding: UTF-8
1 files indexed
Found 0 issue(s)
Done in 23 ms
```

Comment: which issues it is not reporting? do you use custom plugins, like checkstyle or findbugs? those issues will not be displayed as they are custom analyzers and sonarlint is only supporting "Sonar"-analysers (SonarJava, SonarJS, ...)

Comment: Straight "out of the box". So Sonar way profiles and quality gates. No plugins at all.

Comment: Issues not being reported are simple issues like "reorder modifiers to comply with java" or "remove unused import". These issues are on the SonarQube server, but Sonarlint doesn't show them.

Answer (score 3):

SonarLint 3.2 is incompatible with the server 5.6.6 version. We had to revert to version 2.5.1 of SonarLint. After we did that, we see issues from SonarLint itself and from the server.

Upgrading the server was not possible in our situation.